# jhipster gateway and microservice

Tags: microservices, jhipster, gateway

I need to run my gateway and microservice in local without docker. Is this possible?

I created two projects: gateway and microservice. How can I run in local without docker?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this, you'll need to [download the JHipster Registry](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-registry/releases). Then run it with `java -jar jhipster-registry-*.war`. Then start your gateway and microservice apps as you normally would (with Maven/Gradle, or your IDE).